# Not able to download dlib using pip3 or Pip

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

Trying to download dlib using pip3 install dlib command but getting below exception. HOw to resolve below issue?

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\PATH\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Shiladittya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-40do86q8\\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Shiladittya\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-40do86q8\\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Shiladittya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2kmgy0vh'
       cwd: C:\PATH\\Local\Temp\pip-install-40do86q8\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\
  Complete output (58 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\PATH\\Local\Temp\pip-install-40do86q8\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Shiladittya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-40do86q8\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\Shiladittya\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Shiladittya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-40do86q8\dlib_b343cff879474b048ae9f0f7abe0c9ae\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
  -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):



    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!




  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue so what I did I preferred youtube and watched in one video I am sharing the link to that video that might help

[Video Link](https://youtu.be/sz25xxF_AVE)

for short I download visual studio downloader and installed C++ dependencies and first I installed CMake then dlib because dlib takes C++ dependencies then I choose the specified version of dlib and it worked fine but if still, it doesn't work so again

I would recommend using conda environment in conda it works properly but make sure to use basic dependencies (C++ and Cmake)

Comment: Is there any limitation in windows 10 OS.. Because I am using windows 10 as OS

Comment: No, you can use this infect I have used dlib to make my projects and I have used in 2 projects, my friend faced the same so in his system, it worked properly in conda environment but in my system, I used pip environment there is some bug in update version so in the video they recommended to use specific to prefer that one, but before that please use dependency first

i have used same in windows but can't say about linux

and if you like my answer then please follow me and upvote my answers I would be very happy